# how to execute PowerShell script inside an event receiver from sharepoint online

Tags: event-receivers

I want to execute a powershell script from an event receiver. The event receiver is triggered whenever an new item is added to my custom list in sharepoint online site.

Comment: You won't be able to do that.

Comment: can event receiver make a call to other url? If so - maybe http-triggered Azure Function could help

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do in Powershell, you should be able to convert in code behind. If you start another post on that, maybe I could help convert it. But if that is too cumbersome, try this post:

http://devinfra-us.blogspot.ca/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html

Or you could try running a process object from your receiver (something I've only tested with executables)

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Approvals.ps1";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Can i hardcode my powershell script inside the event receiver code.Because i want to run this event receiver from sharepoint online.

Comment: Powershell script cannot be deployed to sharepoint online.

Comment: I guess I should read the title of the post. Sorry